# MySQL Fetch Order

Tags: php, mysql, object, forum

I'm having some troubles. I'm testing out a forum that I created and I'm having a few troubles with  echo'ing out the database stuff.

Here's the source:

```
$getThreads = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM Threads 
    WHERE 
        tid='$ID' 
        AND Type='regular' 
    ORDER BY bump DESC LIMIT {$Minimum},  ". $Setting["PerPage"]);

while ($gT = mysql_fetch_object($getThreads)) {
```

And here is the error,

Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a8118489/public_html/Forum/ViewTopic.php on line 680

Comment: 1) Don't use mysql_* because it's deprecated. 2) Try adding error reporting to your query: mysql_query(...) or die mysql_error());

Comment: dylan i deleted my answer, as i dont think you need any more. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not an answer in my point of view, on repeated request I'll give the code you should use instead:

```
$getThreads = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Threads WHERE tid='$ID' AND Type='regular' ORDER BY bump DESC LIMIT {$Minimum},  ". $Setting["PerPage"]) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Alright thanks, it works.. but now I have this 'Unknown column 'bump' in 'order clause'

Comment: So that means your query is wrong :) It's trying to look for a column named "bump" in your table that doesn't exist :)